# How can I make a function that, when clicked, starts permanently changing the background color and able to click again to stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a function that colors in the grid black everywhere that the mouse hovers, but only after you click. Also, clicking again should stop the coloring.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
        $('.grid').append('<div class="pixel"></div>');
    };
    clickDraw();
    draw();
});

var drawOn = this.false;
var clickDraw = function(){
    $('.grid').click(function(){
        $(drawOn).toggle();
    });
}
var draw = function(){
    if (drawOn === true){
        $('.pixel').mouseenter(function(){
            (this).css("background-color", "black");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: How do I create the function I proposed? This isn't working for some reason I can't figure out.

Comment: this.false is undefined. Will work but just using false would be better...

Comment: Yeah, I was getting desperate. It still doesn't run when I change it to just false.

Comment: Hint.... toggle a class on the element with click. Use `hover()` and in that event handler see if the class exists or not. If it does toggle another class that changes the color through css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, try the following instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
        $('.grid').append('<div class="pixel">&nbsp;</div>');
    };
    clickDraw();
    draw();
});

var drawOn = false;
var clickDraw = function(){
    $('.grid').mousedown(function(){
        if(drawOn) {
                drawOn = false;
        } else {
                drawOn = true;
        }
    });
}
var draw = function(){
    $('.pixel').mouseenter(function(){
            if(drawOn) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "black");
        }
    });
}
```

This toggles `drawOn` between `true` and `false` if you click on the grid, and if `drawOn` is true when the event `mouseenter` executes on a pixel, it changes the background color. Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xc6245v9/1/